# Find irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_{3} [x]$ having as roots $a + 1$ and $a - 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

$x^{2} + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{3} [x]$, and so K = $\mathbb{Z}_{3} [x] / \langle x^{2}+ 1\rangle$ is a field with 9 elements. Let $a$ in K be a root of $f(x)$. Find irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_{3} [x]$ having $a + 1$ and $a - 1$ as roots respectively.

No clue... is it simply plugging $a + 1$ into $f(a) = a^{2}+ 1$, so that $g(a) = (a + 1)^{2}+ 1$, hence $g(x) = x^{2}+ 2x + 2$, which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{3} [x]$?

Thanks!!

Comment: For $\LaTeX$ just add $ on your formulas. Like `$x^2+1$`

Comment: @Cortizol fixed - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, your field $K$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$, so we should try squaring $a+1$ to find some relation. $(a+1)^2=a^2+2a+1 = 2a$ (since $a^2 +1 = 0$), so we have the relation $(a+1)^2 - 2a = 0$. But we want this to be a polynomial in $a+1$, so we can rewrite this as $$(a+1)^2 -2a -2 +2=0$$ or $$(a+1)^2 -2(a+1)+2,$$ so $a+1$ satisfies the polynomial $x^2-2x+2$.

I think your error is that $a+1$ is not not necessarily a root of $f$, which is what you seem to be trying.

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph . So in $Z_{3}$, this is equivalent to $x^{2}+x+2$ ?

Comment: @user113255 Right since $-2 = 1$. The case for $a-1$ is similar, and you have to show the polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$; do you see why that's the case?

Comment: I think what's confusing is that $a \in K$ is a root of $f(x)$... $K$ has 9 elements so does that mean $a$ is one of these 9 elements?

Comment: @user113255 Yes it is; when I was learning this stuff I found it helpful to write out all the elements (of finite fields $K$ constructed this way) explicitly and write out a multiplication table. In essence you are adjoining a square root of $-1$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and calling it $a$. This is similar to how $\mathbb{C}$ is constructed algebraically via $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Comment: then how do you know which of the 9 elements is a root of $f(x)$??

Comment: @user113255 The way you constructed the field $K$ was by adjoining an element $a$ which is a root of $x^2+1$ (i.e. an element $a$ with $a^2=-1$). So you know that $a$ is one root. Now you can factor out $(x-a)$ to get $x^2+1=(x-a)(x+a)$, so the other root has to be $-a$ or equivalently $2a$.

Comment: @user113255 Here's how I'm thinking: What is $K$? It's a set of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Except you are declaring that $x^2+1=0$, so any time you see an $x^2$, you can replace it with a $-1$. So there are only so many possible polynomials: We still have 0, 1, 2, but we can have $x$, $x+1$ and $x+2$, and also $2x$, $2x+1$ and $2x+2$. Everything else is quadratic or higher, so we can reduce it to one of those nine. Now you can forget that those are polynomials (and we can do this by replacing $x$ with $a$, maybe).

Comment: ... So now we know concretely that $K = \{0,1,2,a,a+1,a+2,2a,2a+1,2a+2\}$, and we can multiply just by using the usual algebraic laws (distributivity, etc.) along with the fact that $a^2=-1$. Then asking "what are the roots of $x^2+1$" is the same as asking "which of these nine elements give me $-1$ when I square them?"